# How to fetch multiple rows with specific ID from a table with just one query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Is there a way in Postgres to fetch a list of rows having specific IDs from a table, using one query without any subqueries.

```
Table
id  value
---------
0 | 12
2 | 345
3 | Alan
4 | 0.345
5 | 232333.2
```

I want fetch rows with IDs 2, 3, and 5 using just one query.

Comment: `select * from t where id in (2, 3, 5)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IN` operator as shown in previous answers. However if your list of requested IDs can be empty this will not work because `IN ()` is a syntax error.

If you want to handle the empty list with the same query you can use the `ANY` function:

```
SELECT * FROM "Table"
WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[2, 3, 5]::int[])
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE id IN (2, 3, 5);

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IN` clause

> The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id IN (2, 3, 5);
```